# S3 to GCS Artifacts binaries migration issue

Tags: artifactory

Artifactory is not able to propagate data from object storage.

Migrated all s3 objects of Artifactory hosted on AWS ec2 to GCS buckets. But Artifactory hosted on GCP VM not showing package content and docker images size data on UI still.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear here. But from the question it sounds like you have just moved the binaries, which represents the physical files, without moving the database information as well.

The DB is where Artifactory stores all the Metadata, from file names, to paths to build-info, without it, the binaries are meaningless to the system.

You can bring across this Data from one Artifactory to another using a system export (exclude content as this is the binaries you have manually moved) then import to the new system including content. Artifactory will then match the metadata to the binaries you moved manually.

This process is described here: https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-what-is-the-best-way-to-migrate-a-large-artifactory-instance-with-minimal-downtime

You can achieve something similar by taking a DB dump from the original instance and then importing that to your DB on the new instance.

If this does not answer your question, please can you provide more details about exactly what you have done, and what is not working.

You can always reach out to Jfrog support as well for help.

Comment: Hey David thanks for your response. I already did all things that you mentioned which include taking system export then importing and DB dump restore to get metadata. But the thing is to bring the content of artifacts without using the replication method we wanted to go via storage transfer service in GCP which just migrate all S3 objects to GCS buckets and it is then expected that GCP JFROG now should show the content of the artifact. But this is not working GCP JFROG not showing content only has metadata due to Dump and restore.

Comment: You only need to do one of the 2 options. Either DB dump **or** system export import.
You first should do the storage transfer to the GCP bucket, then do the above.
If the UI does not show the Artifacts, something went wrong with the DB restore/system import. If the Artifacts show but you can't download them, then something went wrong with the storage transfer.

Comment: Hey David, I tried the same options but still artifactory not able to sync data from GCS Buckets. Do we need to keep the same master keys of AWS Jfrog in GCP Jfrog?

Comment: Yes, the master.key is used to encrypt sensitive DB data. You should ensure you have the same master.key if you are doing a db move or system export/import.

You need to be careful as there will be information now encrypted with the new master.key on the GCP instance (join.key, admin.access.token). You can follow these steps to reset the master.key on your GCP instance: https://jfrog.com/help/r/how-to-recover-the-master-key